# Read directly from std::fstream

Tags: c++, msgpack

I try to serialize a data stream to file using `msgbox`.

The file consists of a header and a unknown amount of entries for the data.

Here is my pseudo code so far:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <msgpack.hpp>
struct Header
{
    std::string s;
    MSGPACK_DEFINE(s);
};
struct Data
{
    int i, j, k;
    MSGPACK_DEFINE(i, j, k);
};

void write()
{
    Header h{ "hello world" };
    Data d1{ 1,2,3 };
    Data d2{ 2,3,4 };

    std::fstream out("output.dat", std::ios::out);
    msgpack::pack(out, h);
    msgpack::pack(out, d1);
    msgpack::pack(out, d2);
    // amount of data entries is unknown until data stream ends
}
```

To read the data back in i use a read method like:

```
void read()
{
    std::fstream in("output.dat");

    // can i use the fstream directly to read the data?
    std::string buffer({ std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(in),
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>() });

    msgpack::unpacker unpacker;
    unpacker.reserve_buffer(buffer.size());
    memcpy(unpacker.buffer(), buffer.data(), buffer.size());
    unpacker.buffer_consumed(buffer.size());

    msgpack::object_handle oh;
    if (unpacker.next(oh))
    {
        auto header = oh->as<Header>();
        while (unpacker.next(oh))
        {
            auto data = oh->as<Data>();
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Now to my question: Is it possible to use the input `fstream` in a similar way as `msgpack::pack` in the `write` method?

And if this is not possible, can i access the `fstream`s char buffer and buffer size directly without copying its content as shown in the `read` function?

Thanks in advance.